# Is it possible to stop the Madman from escaping his yacht?

Tags: desert-strike-return-to-the-gulf

In Desert Strike's third campaign map, one of the missions is to rescue hostages from the madman's yacht, pictured below.

[image: The Madman's Yacht, as the Apache Helicopter dodges incoming missiles launched by the soldiers on board]

The following excerpt from a [strategy guide](http://www.cheatcc.com/psp/sg/desert_strike.txt) on CheatCC details the mission:

> When you first get there, shoot soldiers on the deck and take out all vehicles hanging about. Then shoot a hole in the yacht.  You will see hostages float out the south side, and when you go to pick them up, Mubaba escapes in a speedboat from the north side.

Now, I've owned this game for a long time, but I was never able to destroy the madman's speedboat, and neither was the writer of the guide, as he goes on to say:

> I don't know if you can stop him; I never have.

However I was playing the game the other day, and whilst I didn't stop the speedboat, I did notice in the mission debriefing "*Now the bad News*" section that I lost 500 points for "*The madman escaped*"

Does this mean it IS possible to take him out there? Or is this one of those unavoidable no-win scenarios with a guaranteed point loss?

<sub>Note that there is a 4th campaign map that wouldn't make sense if the madman died, but I'm assuming that either his second in command takes over or that ends the game prematurely.</sub>

Comment: I want to play desert strike now!

Comment: @Ric - It is a pretty awesome game, one of my favourites :-).

Comment: Would require a lot of precision, timing and position, but what if you ran out of fuel directly above his speedboat? Pretty much anything that can be destroyed will be destroyed if your helicopter breaks and crash lands on it. Though what would happen if he could be stopped then? Turns out to be a decoy and it goes on as normal? Complete the game early? Just return to base to be told you have won? Level 4 goes ahead with slight changes, it's now his second in command in charge?

Comment: @giulano - Fuel doesn't get consumed over water - but interesting point - you could have the same effect by being shot down (running out of Armor) - definitely requires further testing!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to one of the trolls in Desert Strike. The madman will always escape and you will always lose 500 points. This troll is just to make the player angry and to constantly retry.

On [Sega's wiki](http://sega.wikia.com/wiki/Desert_Strike_Return_to_the_Gulf) it gives you a list of objectives in Mission #3. Notice how it doesn't say anything about possibly killing the madman. As you said earlier it would make Mission #4 impossible to understand.

Comment: Let's keep comments constructive and on-topic.  If extended discussion is required, take it to meta guys.